# Why does TypeScript force me to explicitly pass undefined for an argument that's typed as undefined in my function signature?

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm a junior dev and I need help. I've tried googling the problem, but I'm having a hard time phrasing it the right way. Sorry in advance if the question is misleading.

Can someone please help me understand why TypeScript is forcing me to pass undefined as an argument to a function when I have the parameter typed as undefined in the function signature?

Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to create a function that returns action-creator functions, which then return action objects:

```
interface IAction<T, P> {
    type: T;
    payload?: P;
}

const createActionCreator = <T extends string, P = undefined>(type: T) => (payload: P): IAction<T, P> => ({
    type,
    payload,
});

const THIS_IS_MY_ACTION_TYPE = '@PREFIXED/THIS_IS_MY_ACTION_TYPE';

const createTestAction1 = createActionCreator<typeof THIS_IS_MY_ACTION_TYPE, string>(THIS_IS_MY_ACTION_TYPE);

const createTestAction2 = createActionCreator<typeof THIS_IS_MY_ACTION_TYPE>(THIS_IS_MY_ACTION_TYPE);

const testAction1 = createTestAction1('some string');
// works fine

const testAction2 = createTestAction2();
// TypeScript complains that an argument was expected
```

When I invoke `createActionCreator` providing both the `T` and `P` types, TypeScript forces me to invoke `createTestAction1` with an argument that matches the `P` type. This is what I expect.

When I invoke `createActionCreator` *without* providing the `P`, or even if I provide the `P` as `undefined` explicitly, TypeScript forces me to invoke `createTestAction2` with `undefined` as an argument. I would expect to be able to invoke it without an argument.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand why it behaves this way and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your solution as a separate answer to the question instead of appending it as part of the question. enter it the **Your Answer** box below. other users may upvote it, and you can accept it as the official answer (by clicking the check mark) after 2 days. both will earn you more reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

The function `(payload: P) => {..}` has one parameter, so Typescript expects an argument, even if the parameter type is `undefined`. Try making the parameter optional (using `?`), and then remove the default `= undefined` type from your type param `<P>`.

```
const createActionCreator = <T extends string, P>(type: T) =>
//                                             ^ type `P` is required
    (payload?: P): IAction<T, P> => ({
    //      ^ parameter `payload` is optional
        type,
        payload, // if not provided, will be the value `undefined`
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I don't want the payload to be optional if I provide a payload type when I invoke `createActionCreator `. I want the payload to either be either required or omitted. I did some more digging and found a way to achieve this by using function signature overloading and by passing a payloadRequired argument along with my type, then conditionally returning the second function with and without the payload parameter.

Comment: @AdamBelton — Glad you could find a solution! Would you mind posting it in your own answer? [This is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), because it could help other users who have the same problem. Not to mention, you can mark your own answer as "accepted" after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with function signature overloading and a payloadRequired argument in the first invocation, to determine whether to return the inner function with or without a payload parameter:

```
export interface IAction<T extends IActionConstant, P = undefined> {
    type: T;
    payload?: P;
}

export function createActionCreator<T extends IActionConstant, P = 'Please provide a type definition for the payload'>(
    type: T,
    config: { withPayload: true }
): (payload: P) => IAction<T, P>;
export function createActionCreator<T extends IActionConstant>(
    type: T,
    config: { withPayload: false }
): () => IAction<T>;
export function createActionCreator<T extends IActionConstant, P>(type: T, config: { withPayload: boolean }) {
    if (config.withPayload) {
        return function createAction(payload: P) {
            return {
                type,
                payload,
            };
        };
    }
    return function createAction() {
        return {
            type,
        };
    };
}
```